# Getting Different Results from Python Interpreter and Pycharm

Tags: python, pycharm, interpreter

I am beginner in learning Python programming. When I run this simple script in Pycharm 2021.1.2 (community edition), I got the result I expected:

```
a = 1000
b = 1000
print(a is b)
True
```

But when I run the same in Python interpreter 3.9.4, I got a different result:

```
>>> a = 1000
>>> b = 1000
>>> print(a is b)
False
```

My question is why the difference? Which of Pycharm and interpreter is the most recommended for beginners like me to continue to learn Python?

Comment: Most likely what you should actually be doing is `a == b`, comparing by _equality_ not _identity_.

Answer (score -1):

Hey I use both interpreters and my answer is that they're all the same.